# How can I dynamically do write a value into a function call?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<asp:LinkButton class="uibutton normal submit" ID="LinkButtonMAR" 
OnClick="MarkClientNoteRead(<%# Eval("NoteID") %>)" runat="server">
Mark as Read</asp:LinkButton>
```

This is all within a repeater that will return a list of notes.  I want to grab the NoteID and throw this into the `OnClick="MarkClientNoteRead()"` method call.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`CommandArgument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.commandargument):

```
<asp:LinkButton class="uibutton normal submit" 
     ID="LinkButtonMAR" 
     CommandName="MarkRead"
     CommandArgument='<%# Eval("NoteID") %>'
     Text="Mark as Read"
     OnCommand="MarkClientNoteRead" runat="server" />

protected void MarkClientNoteRead(Object sender, CommandEventArgs e) 
{
     int NoteID = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
}
```

Note that you need to handle the [`Command`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.command.aspx) event instead of the `Click` event.

Comment: @JamesWilson: Anyway, i've edited my answer since you need to handle the `Command` event instead which is also triggered when the LinkButton is clicked but passes the CommandEventArgs.

Comment: Worked perfectly!  Thanks for helping me be less of a noob coder. :)

Answer (score 0):

Another more convoluted way would be:

```
<asp:LinkButton class="uibutton normal submit" ID="LinkButtonMAR" 
    OnClick="LinkButtonMAR_Click" runat="server">Mark as Read
</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:HiddenField ID="NoteID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("NoteID")%>' />
```

Code Behind:

```
protected void LinkButtonMAR_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton thisLinkBUtton = (LinkButton)sender;
    // substitute appropriate object for the GridViewRow below
    GridViewRow thisGridViewRow = (GridViewRow)thisLinkBUtton.Parent.Parent;
    HiddenField hdnNoteID = (HiddenField)thisGridViewRow.FindControl("NoteID"); 
    // run your update code...
}
```

I've used this, but it bothers me having to use Parent.Parent.  Plus, I was needing other bits of data from the same row.

Comment: OP is using a Repeater not a GridView. Apart from that you should use thisLinkBUtton.NamingContainer to get the reference to the GridViewRow. But this works also for Repeater by casting LinkButton.NamingContainer to RepeaterItem.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thank you for the tip about the NamingContainer.  I'll try that in my code.